# Java 8: How to parse DayOfWeek with locale set by device

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8, dayofweek

Why is it that whenever I set a `DayOfWeek` for my `TextView` the output always appears in capital letters? Also, the day never changes when the language of my device is changed. How can it be set to change based on the device's current locale?

```
    myTv.text = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.toString()
```

**Output**

```
MONDAY
```

Comment: You are `toString`-ing the enum. So you get back the name of the enum itself. That is not the display-name. You get that by using `getDisplayName`. Also see the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do (replace Locale accordingly...)

```
String day = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: `Locale.getDefault()` solves the problem more efficiently.

Comment: @MacaronLover good point & updated. I was hard coding OP's Locale based on his profile :)